# Random Forest Classifier decision path method (scikit)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I've implemented a standard randomforestclassifier on the titanic dataset, and hope to explore sklearn's decision_path method which was introduced in v0.18. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

However, it outputs a sparse matrix which I'm not certain how to make sense of. Can anyone advise on how best to visualise this?

```
#Training a simplified random forest
estimator = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_estimators=3, max_depth=3)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Extracting the decision path for instance i = 12
i_data = X_test.iloc[12].values.reshape(1,-1)
d_path = rf_best.decision_path(i_data)

print(d_path)
```

Output:

> (<1x3982 sparse matrix of type ''    with 598
>   stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, array([   0,   45,
>   98,  149,  190,  233,  258,  309,  360,  401,  430,
>           461,  512,  541,  580,  623,  668,  711,  760,  803,  852,  889,
>           932,  981, 1006, 1035, 1074, 1107, 1136, 1165, 1196, 1241, 1262,
>          1313, 1350, 1385, 1420, 1465, 1518, 1553, 1590, 1625, 1672, 1707,
>          1744, 1787, 1812, 1863, 1904, 1945, 1982, 2017, 2054, 2097, 2142,
>          2191, 2228, 2267, 2304, 2343, 2390, 2419, 2456, 2489, 2534, 2583,
>          2632, 2677, 2714, 2739, 2786, 2833, 2886, 2919, 2960, 2995, 3032,
>          3073, 3126, 3157, 3194, 3239, 3274, 3313, 3354, 3409, 3458, 3483,
>          3516, 3539, 3590, 3629, 3660, 3707, 3750, 3777, 3822, 3861, 3898,
>          3939, 3982], dtype=int32))

Apologies if I'm not providing enough detail - do let me know otherwise.

Thanks!

**Note:** Edited to simplify random forest (limit depth and n_trees)

Comment: You might want to start with a tiny sample dataset and use only a few trees in the forest to make the result simpler.

Comment: I would be interested to know this as well. From the documentation it's not very clear to how to interpret the output. The only thing I know of is that Sklearn has a tutorial on how to visualize the decision surface: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_iris.html

Comment: @BrenBarn I've reduced the number of trees to make the result simpler and only used a single instance of data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to visualize the trees in the forest you could try the answer provided here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/118016

Adapting to your problem:

```
from sklearn import tree

...

i_tree = 0
for tree_in_forest in estimator.estimators_:
    with open('tree_' + str(i_tree) + '.dot', 'w') as my_file:
        my_file = tree.export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file = my_file)
    i_tree = i_tree + 1
```

This will create 10 (default number of trees in the forest) files called tree_i.dot for i = 0 to 9.  You can create pdf files for each one of them doing at the terminal (for example):

```
$ dot -Tpdf tree_0.dot -o tree.pdf
```

Probably there's a smarter way to do it, I'd be happy to learn it if anyone could help :)

Comment: Thanks Luciana. While this is no doubt useful, we are still stuck with the problem of visualising the decision path of the whole forest (as opposed to individual trees).

Comment: @jc023.I have same doubt.Have you found the solution?Can you help me in interpreting the results

Comment: @Jayashree there's the [TreeInterpreter](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter) package that works with forests as well.

Comment: @ldavid , the TreeIntrepeter expsoes the feature contributions rather than the decision_path of the algorithm